# How to send values from one jsp page to other but redirect to some other page?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, netbeans

I want to send values from jsp1.jsp to jsp2.jsp but redirect jsp1.jsp to jsp3.jsp . I used the following code in servlet for jsp1
           `response.sendRedirect("welcome1.jsp");
            request.setAttribute("usern",user);
            RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("afterlogin.jsp");
            rd.forward(request,response);`
but it keeps on giving this error "org.apache.jasper.JasperException: PWC6033: Error in Javac compilation for JSP".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a HttpSession object as a user session, or use the ServletContext object for sharing global application information. Then use methods getAttribute (String attb) and setAttribute (String attb, String value) for sharing information within JSPs. The issue when you use a request is that the domain of the request is constraining you to use this information only when you receive this request.

You can also use JavaBeans to share information within JSPs

EDIT: Have you included your Java code inside a scriptlet? Using <% your code here %>

Comment: jasper! I am using a servlet (models.java) for redirecting and retrieving data so i don't need to put my code in these <%  %>

Comment: Please check that you are not using any variable in the JSP that you have not declared before. You are getting a compilation error in the JSP which is strange if you have not included any Java code in it

Comment: Yeah!! you are correct jasper..I was using an undeclared variable..Thank you for help!!

Comment: No problem! Glad to be of help.

Answer (score 1):

you can use the possiblites of sessions in those case so you can access the parameter in jsp2 and redirect the jsp 1 to 3

https://www.javatpoint.com/servlet-http-session-login-and-logout-example
http://java.candidjava.com/tutorial/Servlet-Jsp-HttpSession-Login-logout-example.htm

Answer (score 0):

when you are using the sendRedirect function it will immediately redirect to that page it will not read next line code.

So according to your code your compiler is smart enough to check it so it is giving you an error.

please see below

1) SendRedirect ():

This method is declared in HttpServletResponse Interface. 
Signature: void sendRedirect(String url)

1)In case of sendRedirect request is transfer to another resource to different domain or different server for further processing. 
2)When you use SendRedirect container transfers the request to client or browser so URL given inside the sendRedirect method is visible as a new request to the client. 
3)In case of SendRedirect call old request and response object is lost because it’s treated as new request by the browser. 
4)SendRedirect is slower because one extra round trip is required because completely new request is created and old request object is lost.Two browser request required. 
5)But in sendRedirect if we want to use we have to store the data in session or pass along with the URL.

2) Forward():

This method is declared in RequestDispatcher Interface. 
Signature: forward(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response)

1)When we use forward method request is transfer to other resource within the same server for further processing. 
2)In case of forward Web container handle all process internally and client or browser is not involved. 
3)When forward is called on requestdispather object we pass request and response object so our old request object is present on new resource which is going to process our request
4)Using forward () method is faster then send redirect. 
5)When we redirect using forward and we want to use same data in new resource we can use request. setAttribute() as we have request object available.

more in : https://www.javatpoint.com/q/3577/difference-between-requestdispatcher-and-sendredirect